# Gnuplot video Output With Colour Plot

Tags: arrays, video, time, gnuplot

I'm trying to use gnuplot to create a video file of an array of data points updating with time.  The format of the data file is:
time << x << y << value.

The values are either +- 1, and so +1 should correspond to 1 colour, and -1 to another.
As each time step is taken, the corresponding coordinate should be updated, replacing any old value which may be present.

Unfortunately I am very unfamiliar with gnuplot, and am at quite a loss as to how to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: How is the data structured?  Is it just a scatter of points or is it on a regular grid?